# Why does a classical solution of the wave equation have to be $C^2$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

A (classical) solution of the wave equation
$$
u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0,\qquad (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*_+,
$$
is required to be of class $C^2$. Why?

I mean, why would one impose that all second partial derivatives, even $u_{xt}$ , which does not appear in the PDE, must be continuous?!

Answer (score 5):

You are right, it is some overkill. I guess you could require something like $$ u\big(x, \cdot\big) \in C^2\big(\mathbb{R}\big) \land u\big(\cdot, t \big) \in C^2\big(\mathbb{R}_+\big),$$ which is a minimal less restricted case although you probably just exclude some very specially tailored counterexamples.

Comment: Are you using Taylor series to tailor these counterexamples? 

Comment: Forgive my English :D